# Need help fixing salt stack code to copy file from s3 bucket

Tags: salt-stack, salt-cloud

I wrote this code to pull file from S3 bucket, change the file permission and execute the code. However, it's not working for me.

```
download_file_from_s3:
  file.managed:
    - name: /opt/agent_installer.sh
    - source: s3://bucket_name/install.sh

change_file_permission:
  file.managed:
    - source: /opt/install.sh
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 0744

run_rapid7_script:
  cmd.run:
    - name: /opt/install.sh
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome here. The code you have shown does 3 actions. When you say "*it's not working*", what exactly is not working? Please update the question with any errors and details.

Comment: Hi, @seshadri_c I am pretty new to salt stack. This is my first salt code. My salt-master server is really messed up now. Can you help use your Midas eye to check the code and let me know if it's ok or not? I am guessing I need an access key to access the s3 bucket but I don't know how to pass that.

Comment: I could spot a couple of things that could be changed, but I'm not sure if that is your issue. That's why, it will help to know what error you are getting or what is not working.

Comment: Please help fix the one that you can @seshadri_c. It would be nice to know where I made the mistakes. I will later check it today when the salt master server is back up

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of changes I can suggest looking at your code.

You are saving the file from S3 as `/opt/agent_installer.sh` with `file.managed`, let's consider that there is no issue with this.

Now, the first thing that we obviously need to change in subsequent tasks, is to use this. Not `/opt/install.sh`. Also `file.managed` can be used once to download the file, change ownership, and permissions. So your SLS can look like:

```yaml
download_file_from_s3:
  file.managed:
    - name: /opt/agent_installer.sh
    - source: s3://bucket_name/install.sh
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 0744

run_rapid7_script:
  cmd.run:
    - name: /opt/agent_installer.sh
```

There is also a `cmd.script` state which can be used directly with the S3 URL as `source`, so there is no need to have `file.managed` at all.

So, just 1 state like below should be sufficient:

```yaml
run_rapid7_script:
  cmd.script:
    - source: s3://bucket_name/install.sh
```

---

If you do have issue with downloading file from S3, then see the [documentation](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/3003/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.s3.html) on how to configure it correctly.

Comment: Thanks so much @seshadri_c. I really appreciate your help